# jQuery interval restart after reaching last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a few p elements in it and I loop over them with jQuery to trigger a click on the next element every 5 seconds. Now my questions how can I restart the loop when the last element has been clicked?

This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.clickMe').each(function (ind, elem) {    
   window.setTimeout(function () {
       jQuery(elem).trigger("click");
   }, 5000 * ind);          
});
```

This is my html incase you want to see it :)

```
<div class='slider-circles'>
   <p class='transparent-cricles clickMe'></p>
   <p class='transparent-cricles clickMe'></p>
   <p class='transparent-cricles clickMe'></p>
   <p class='transparent-cricles clickMe'></p>
   <p class='transparent-cricles clickMe'></p>
   <p class='transparent-cricles clickMe'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: use a counter and reset it once it reaches the last element

Comment: What exactly do I need the counter for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ps=jQuery('.clickMe')
if (ps.length) {
    var index=0;
    setInterval(function() {
        ps.eq(index).trigger("click");
        index=(index+1)%ps.length;
    },5000);
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution IMO Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
  logic();
}, 600);
});

function logic(){
   window.setTimeout(function () {
       $('.clickMe').each(function (ind, elem) {    
        window.setTimeout(function () {
           $(elem).hide();
           if(ind % 5 == 0) $('.clickMe').show();
           console.log(ind);
       }, 100 * ind);          
        });  
   },600 );
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3how0tm0/1/

You need to reset them after every loop.
To visualize i'm hiding and showing your `<p>`-tags. You need to add and remove the trigger Event.

Answer (score 0):

Add and remove class to know that you've clicked.

```
var initiliazeClicks = function() {
  jQuery('.clickMe').each(function(ind, elem) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {


    jQuery(elem).addClass('clicked').removeClass('clickMe').trigger('click');

          if (jQuery('.clickMe').length == 0) {
            jQuery('.clicked').removeClass('clicked').addClass('clickMe');
            initiliazeClicks();

          }

        }, 5000 * ind);
      });

    };


    initiliazeClicks();
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/zsek6c2a/

Answer (score 0):

After last click, run all clicking again:

```
function run_clicking(elements) {
  var last_index = elements.length - 1;
  elements.each(function () (index, elem) {
                  window.setTimeout(function () {
                       jQuery(elem).trigger("click");
                       if( index == last_index ) {
                           // when last element, run it again (after 5s)
                           window.setTimeout(function () {
                                  run_clicking(elements);
                           }, 5000);
                       }
                   }, 5000 * index);
   }
}
run_clicking(jQuery('.clickMe'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom function to restart the loop when the last element is reached:

```
function performInfiniteClick(){
  var len = performInfiniteClick.counter;
  $('.clickMe').each(function (i, el) {
     window.setTimeout(function () {
       $(el).trigger("click");
       len--;
       if (!len) {
          performInfiniteClick();
       }
     }, 1000 * i);          
  });
  return true;
}
performInfiniteClick.counter = $('.clickMe').length;

performInfiniteClick();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7g3eo93m/